# Is there any Javascript library to process sound files (.mp3, .wav)?

Tags: javascript, audio, node.js

I have some task where i have to check the quality of sound in .wav file

**Following things i need to identify:**

- To detect Audio files with so much background noise in it.
- To check whether the volume is too low as not to be recognizable.

Is there any JS library , where i can achieve above mentioned functionalities ? I am using AWS Lambda-Node js for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

#### For MP3

You have two options, both bindings against software created by the excellent [LAME Project](https://lame.sourceforge.io/).

The [lame](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lame) npm package is a full-featured binding against the [libmp3lame](https://github.com/gypified/libmp3lame) C library. I would recommend this unequivocally, except that it hasn't been updated in four years.

You could also use the [node-lame](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-lame) npm package. It is a wrapper around the [lame CLI tool](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lame), instead of the C library. The performance is much worse because of this, but it is simpler to use. It is also updated more frequently than the previously mentioned alternative.

#### For WAV

You can use the [wavefile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavefile) npm package.

#### For Ogg/Vorbis

You should use the [ogg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ogg) npm package. The fork by [@suldashi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@suldashi/ogg) is much more frequently maintained than the primary repo. You might also need [node-vorbis](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-vorbis) to handle decoding.